# Responsividade para resolução especifica?

Tags: html, css

Olá, sou iniciante na programação web , mas já desenvolvi um site responsivo, agora em meu segundo projeto que é um portfólio estou tendo dúvidas platônicas que me atormentam.
O problema é que nele fiz uma janelinha que abre ao acionar um botão, quase que um popup mesmo, e quero que essa tela não crie uma barra de rolagem por conta de seu tamanho.
Até ai tranquilo, começei a trabalhar na responsividade e simplesmente "bugei", normalmente vou regulando de acordo com o width, ficou legal para uma tela de 1600 x 1024, mas totalmente desproporcional para 1600x900.
Queria saber se existe um modo de levar em conta a largura e a altura de uma resolução especifica, vou tentar exemplificar usando uma "lógica de css" a baixo:

@media screen and (1600x1024){}

@media screen and (1600x900){}

Já me desculpo pela falta de linguagem técnica, existe algo do tipo ?

Comment: [Este artigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) pode te ajudar.

Comment: Você pode usar o Vh pra altura, as vzs é melhor em caso de responsividade.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar esse problema, existem duas opções:

Você pode utilizar o media query para width e height utilizando virgulas, por exemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px), screen and (max-height: 1024px) {
  ...
}
```

ou também utilizando apenas o "and", como no exemplo abaixo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (max-height: 900px) {
  ...
}
```